# Javascript redirecting not working

Tags: javascript

```
<body class='gray'>
    <section>
        <i class='icon-loading i-large animate-spin'></i>

        <h1>Redirecting to your new destination</h1>

        <table class="most-width table-column-only center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h2>From</h2></th>
                    <th><h2>To</h2></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id='old'></td>
                    <td id='new'></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thishost = "google.com";
    var thathost = "amazon.com";
    var url = window.location.href.toString();

    var current = document.getElementById('old');
    var new = document.getElementById('new');

    current.innerHTML = 'Current URL: ' + url;

    var newurl = url.replace(thishost, thathost);

    new.innerHTML = 'New URL: ' + newurl;
    window.location = newurl;
</script>
```

This is a simple page I tried to throw together to just overwrite the first portion of the URL (i.e. the domain) and replace it with a different host.

It just doesn't want to work at all. It doesn't even change the innerHTML of the table cells. Am I doing something very obviously wrong?

Comment: `new` is a reserved word...

Comment: ...which is something you'd have immediately noticed if you'd looked at the browser's error console.

Comment: …or if you’d looked at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the syntax highlighting for Atom (github's new text-editor) didn't differentiate.

@Xufox I meant to say "(i.e. the domain)", fixed the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, your issue is that you are using the reserved keyword `new` for a variable.  Replace `new` with `newtd` or the like and it should work.

In future though, you can catch these syntax errors yourself by going to your browser's debugger/javascript console (Option+Command+J on Chrome for instance).  It will tell you the problem line and some indication of what the problem is:

[image]

Alternately, *JSHint* on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) can give you much the same information.

[image]